# Problems with 3D after upgrading

Tags: drivers, upgrade, 13.04, graphics

I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04. I use Sweet Home 3D. After upgrading, my driver for graphics `Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV 610` doesn't display correctly anymore in 3D. The screen fills with pixels and strange signs when moving with the mouse, it flickers and I ask myself if I should upgrade the graphics driver? But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install the latest AMD drivers for you graphic card, I recommend you to build the .deb packages using the .run installer of AMD website (follow this tutorial):

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124292/153260)

The latest driver compatible with Ubuntu 13.04 is the 13.6 Beta driver (8 jun): http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-6-beta-x86.x86_64.zip